# How to limit element from expanding past parent div when dynamic elements are added?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Situation:** I'm trying to create a dynamic input box where I can add words to a box to have them display individually in bubbles. To build up to that, I'm trying to have a div container ( ) side by side with an input field (), so when a user adds an element it drops it in the div container displaying both side by side. If you're confused on what I'm trying to achieve I posted a jsfiddle for reference.

**My Issue:** When I add an element to the div container, it expands the size of the container past the maximum size I tried to allocate for it. I set a specific size to the parent div containing everything. I think my issue lies in that, using width=100% for the input box references the parent div which does not change despite adding new elements side by side. How can I make the input text box dynamically resize itself to fill in the left over space and no more?

**My goal:** Figure out how to make the input box dynamically resize to fit the parent container when sibling elements are added side by side to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$('.emotionsInput').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;

    if (key == 13)
    {
        var inputWord = $(this).val();
        var currentCell = $(this);
        createTag(currentCell);
    }
})

function createTag(currentCell)
{
    var parentCell = currentCell.parent()

    var inputWord = currentCell.val();

    currentCell.val("");
    var newTagHTML = '<span class="emotionTag">' + inputWord + '</span>';
    parentCell.children(".emotionTagsDiv").append(newTagHTML);
}
```

```css
#testTagBox > span > span {
    border-color:transparent;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #000;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    display:flex; /* changed this here, it was inline*/
}

#testTagBox > span {
    padding: 0.67rem 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    display:flex; /* changed this here, it was inline-block */ 
}

#testTagBox {
    width: 30rem;
    padding-right:1.8rem;
}

.emotionsDiv {
    display: flex; /* changed this here, it was inline-block */
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.emotionTagsDiv {
    flex: 1 1 auto; /* added this here */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.emotionTag {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

input {
    font-family: Arial;
    display: flex; /* changed this here */
    flex: 20 1 auto; /* added this so that it prioritizes shrinking this element.*/
    width: 100%;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div id="testTagBox">
        <span>
            <span>
                <div class="emotionsDiv">
                    <div class="emotionTagsDiv">

                    </div>
                    <input class="emotionsInput" placeholder="type and press enter here" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6/dist/tippy-bundle.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="testapp.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, when you add an element the entire container resizes when I'm trying to make the input box be fixed on the right side and reduce size on the left so the container stays the same size and everything fits in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width if the input can be adjusted by changing the display property of `.emotionTagsDiv` to `flex`

```js
$('.emotionsInput').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;

    if (key == 13)
    {
        var inputWord = $(this).val();
        var currentCell = $(this);
        createTag(currentCell);
    }
})

function createTag(currentCell)
{
    var parentCell = currentCell.parent()

    var inputWord = currentCell.val();

    currentCell.val("");
    var newTagHTML = '<span class="emotionTag">' + inputWord + '</span>';
    parentCell.children(".emotionTagsDiv").append(newTagHTML);
}
```

```css
#testTagBox > span > span {
    border-color:transparent;
  
 
    padding:5px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

#testTagBox > span {
    padding: 0.67rem 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

#testTagBox {
    max-width: 30rem; 
    padding-right:1.8rem;
}

.emotionsDiv {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
      box-shadow:0 0 0 2px #000;
     padding: .5rem;
       border-radius: 40px;
}

.emotionTagsDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.emotionTag {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

input {
    /* border-style: hidden; */
    font-family: Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 50px; 
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div id="testTagBox">
        <span>
            <span>
                <div class="emotionsDiv">
                    <div class="emotionTagsDiv">

                    </div>
                    <input class="emotionsInput" placeholder="type and press enter here" type="text" value="">
                </div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6/dist/tippy-bundle.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="testapp.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh my, I don't know why I didn't even try this. I heard of flex but didn't think it would make any difference after searching that it is similar to inline-block. I updated all the parent containers to flex display and its working! Thank you!